# How to format user's input text to MM/DD/YYYY using Input Formatter in Flutter

Tags: flutter, validation, user-input

Need to know how to format the user's input text to "MM/DD/YYYY" format. As the user enters the value in input field, the text should be taken in this format, plus let's say if the users type the month as 14, the "4" should not be added. This month, date, year validation needs to be happening as the users types.

This is what I have so far, The month formatting works fine, but needs improvements in date formatting.

```
class _DateFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue prevText, TextEditingValue currText) {
    int selectionIndex;

    // Get the previous and current input strings
    String pText = prevText.text;
    String cText = currText.text;
    // Abbreviate lengths
    int cLen = cText.length;
    int pLen = pText.length;

    //Date

    if (cLen == 1) {
      // Can only be 0, 1, 2 or 3
      if (int.parse(cText) > 1) {
        // Remove char
        cText = '';
      }
    } else if (cLen == 2 && pLen == 1) {
      // Can only be 0, 1, 2 or 3
      if (int.parse(cText) == 0 || int.parse(cText) > 12) {
        // Remove char
        cText = cText.substring(0, 1);
      } else {
        cText += '/';
      }
    } else if (cLen == 2 && pLen == 3) {
      cText = cText.substring(0, 1);
    } else if (cLen == 2 && pLen == 4) {
      cText += '/';
    } else if (cLen == 3 && pLen == 2) {
      cText = cText.substring(0, 2) + '/' + cText.substring(2, 3);
    }

    // Month
    else if (cLen == 4 && pLen == 2) {
      print('s');
      if (int.parse(cText.substring(3, 4)) > 3) {
        cText = cText;
      }
    } else if (cLen == 4 && pLen == 3) {
      if (int.parse(cText.substring(3, 4)) > 3) {
        cText = cText.substring(0, 3);
      }

      // // Can only be 0, 1, 2 or 3
      // if (int.parse(cText) > 3) {
      //   // Remove char
      //   cText = '
      // }
      // // Can only be 0 or 1
      // if (int.parse(cText.substring(3, 4)) > 1) {
      //   // Remove char
      //   cText = cText.substring(0, 3);
      // }
    } else if (cLen == 5 && pLen == 4) {
      // Month cannot be greater than 12
      int mm = int.parse(cText.substring(3, 5));
      if (mm == 0 || mm > 12) {
        // Remove char
        cText = cText.substring(0, 4);
      } else {
        // Add a / char
        cText += '/';
      }
    } else if ((cLen == 3 && pLen == 4) || (cLen == 6 && pLen == 7)) {
      // Remove / char
      cText = cText.substring(0, cText.length - 1);
    } else if (cLen == 3 && pLen == 2) {
      if (int.parse(cText.substring(2, 3)) > 1) {
        // Replace char
        cText = cText.substring(0, 2) + '/';
      } else {
        // Insert / char
        cText =
            cText.substring(0, pLen) + '/' + cText.substring(pLen, pLen + 1);
      }
    }

    //Year

    else if (cLen == 6 && pLen == 5) {
      // Can only be 1 or 2 - if so insert a / char
      int y1 = int.parse(cText.substring(5, 6));
      if (y1 < 1 || y1 > 2) {
        // Replace char
        cText = cText.substring(0, 5) + '/';
      } else {
        // Insert / char
        cText = cText.substring(0, 5) + '/' + cText.substring(5, 6);
      }
    } else if (cLen == 7) {
      // Can only be 1 or 2
      int y1 = int.parse(cText.substring(6, 7));
      if (y1 < 1 || y1 > 2) {
        // Remove char
        cText = cText.substring(0, 6);
      }
    } else if (cLen == 8) {
      // Can only be 19 or 20
      int y2 = int.parse(cText.substring(6, 8));
      if (y2 < 19 || y2 > 20) {
        // Remove char
        cText = cText.substring(0, 7);
      }
    }

    selectionIndex = cText.length;
    print(selectionIndex);
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: cText,
      selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: selectionIndex),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: did you the find solution if so can you share it will helpful to me. Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to follow this package, I hope it would be helpful
https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter

```
var textEditingController = TextEditingController(text: "12345678");
var maskFormatter = new MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: '####-####', filter: { "#": RegExp(r'[0-9]') });

TextField(controller: textEditingController, inputFormatters: [maskFormatter])  // -> "1234-5678"

textEditingController.value = maskFormatter.updateMask(mask: "##-##-##-##");
```

Comment: I've given this Package a try, but the thing is, it let's me to type 14 as a month and then it throws a validation error, but my use case is, it shouldn't let me to type 14 for month.